# SQL query to invert table contents

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table named `Color_Table` which has only one field `Color` and its contents are : 
`Blue`
`Blue`
`Blue`
`Red`
Now I have to update this table's contents so that all records having `Color` = `Blue` are changed to `Color` = `Red` and vice versa. The updated table will look like : 
`Red`
`Red`
`Red`
`Blue`
Here is what I did 
`UPDATE Color_Table
SET Color = "TempRed"
WHERE Color = "Blue";`
`UPDATE Color_Table
SET Color = "Blue"
WHERE Color = "Red";`
`UPDATE Color_Table
SET Color = "Red"
WHERE Color = "TempRed";`
Is there any other where we can do it using less number of queries and without extra space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single `update`:

```
update color_table
    set color = (case when color = 'Blue' then 'Red'
                      when color = 'Red' then 'Blue'
                 end)
    where color in ('Blue', 'Red');
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
UPDATE Color_Table SET Color = 
         CASE WHEN Color='Red' THEN 'Blue' 
              WHEN Color='Blue' THEN 'Red' 
              ELSE Color 
         END
```